# Flutter Desktop Application- NoSuchMethodError: Class "Window" has no istance getter 'locales'

Tags: flutter, flutter-desktop

I'm pretty new on Flutter and I trying to build a desktop app.
I did all steps of following guide: https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-from-mobile-to-desktop-93635e8de64e (Running your own project (compiling the Go desktop project))

Unfornatelly, when I try to run the code I have this error:

**NoSuchMethodError: Class "Window" has no instance getter 'locales' 

Receiver: Instance of Window 

Tried calling: locales**

Thank you in advance

The Operating System is Windows 8.1 and following the code. It is the starter one where I just added the debugDefaultTargetPlatformOverride part.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart' show 
debugDefaultTargetPlatformOverride;

void main(){
debugDefaultTargetPlatformOverride = TargetPlatform.fuchsia;
runApp(MyApp());
}
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(

        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);



  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {

      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(

        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(

        child: Column(

         mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ), 
methods.
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Please include the code in the SO question so that people can review  it inline and do not have to follow the link. (Leave the link in for context though.)

Comment: I added the code and the operating system ;)